# Windsor ResolveAll and multiple UsingFactoryMethod

Tags: castle-windsor

I have next code:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer()
    .Register(Component.For<IAppender>().UsingFactoryMethod(x=>new EventLogAppender()))
    .Register(Component.For<IAppender>().UsingFactoryMethod(x=>new ConsoleAppender()));

var appenders = container.ResulveAll<IAppender>();
```

It fails with KernelException "Could not instantiate custom activator" in Seccond Register line.
I need to configure each Appender separately.
Who can help me to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but if I add Named() to at least one of Registration clause it will fix issue. Looks like a bug.